# Lenovo Battery Conservation mode fail

Tags: power-management, lenovo, tlp, battery-charging-threshold

I've been trying to get battery conservation mode to work by doing the below, but ultimately I have been unable to get the setting to change from 0 to 1

Running kernel 5.11.0-37

Tried previous posted solutions of

`echo 1 > /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode`

however, when I look at the file ...

```
cat /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
0
```

Trying this using sudo su also had no effect.

Also tried editing the file manually as root, but when reopening the file it is once again set to 0

Tried: TLP, which seems to confirm I can set an upper threshold for my Lenovo 7i, but it also references conservation_mode being set as 0 (100%)

```
sudo tlp setcharge 80 1

Setting temporary charge threshold for all batteries: conservation mode = 1


sudo tlp-stat -s -b --cdiff
--- TLP 1.4.0 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings (only differences to defaults):
/etc/tlp.conf L0514: RESTORE_THRESHOLDS_ON_BAT="1"
/etc/tlp.conf L0508: START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1="70"
/etc/tlp.conf L0509: STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1="80"

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO Lenovo Legion 7 15IMHg05 81YU
BIOS           = E9CN62WW(V4.07)
OS Release     = Linux Mint 20.1
Kernel         = 5.11.0-37-generic #41~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 09:06:38 UTC 2021 x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.11.0-37-generic root=UUID=0e11e314-e8c7-4281-b1d0-a2e48e32244b ro nomodeset quiet splash nomodeset acpi_osi=! "acpi_osi=Windows 2020"
Init system    = systemd v245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.13)
Boot mode      = UEFI

+++ TLP Status
State          = enabled
RDW state      = enabled
Last run       = 18:07:12,  20084 sec(s) ago
Mode           = AC
Power source   = AC

+++ Battery Care
Plugin: lenovo
Supported features: charge threshold
Driver usage:
* vendor (ideapad_laptop) = active (charge threshold)
Parameter value range:
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0: 0(off), 1(on) -- battery conservation mode

/sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode = 0 (100%)

+++ Battery Status: BAT1
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/manufacturer                   = 0x53 0x4D 0x50 0x00 0x32 0x30 0x
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/model_name                     = 0x4C 0x31 0x39 0x4D 0x34 0x50 0x8000
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/cycle_count                    =     22
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full_design             =  80000 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_full                    =  77870 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/energy_now                     =  77370 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/status                         = Idle

Charge                                                      =   99.4 [%]
Capacity                                                    =   97.3 [%]
```

If anyone has any possible solutions, explanations on why I cant seem to edit the conservation_mode file, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo tlp setcharge 0 1` and afterwards the one from  `sudo tlp-stat -s -b --cdiff` to your post.

Comment: updated post with requested outputs

Comment: See my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the configuration of TLP is not quite intuitive in this case.

The crucial information is in the output of **tlp-stat -b**.

```
* STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0: 0(off), 1(on) -- battery conservation mode
```

BAT0 because conservation mode applies to all batteries regardless of their name.

For conservation mode you must configure:

```
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=1
```

Then use the terminal command

```
sudo tlp setcharge
```

Check

```
sudo tlp-stat -b
```

Your existing lines may be commented afterwards

```
/etc/tlp.conf L0508: START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1="70"
/etc/tlp.conf L0509: STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT1="80"
```

Comment: even after input of: sudo tlp setcharge 80 1, and it confirming setting it to Conservation mode = 1. I get the same output for tlp-stat -b

Comment: Then your laptop probably ignores the setting. Strange.

Comment: seems to. More so, my confusion is why I cant seem to alter the below even with full permissions. Im at a loss..... /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode

Comment: This is only consistent: TLP can't change it and neither can you by hand.

Answer (score 0):

A direct and simple solution to your problem would be this:

1. Check if Ideapad_laptop kernel module is loaded (You don't need to repeat this)

> lsmod | grep ideapad_laptop

2. To know the current status of conservation mode:

(If Output is 1 - conservation mode ON, 0 - conservation mode OFF)

> cat
> /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode

(You may have different name for "VPC2004:00" so check that by going to the folder "ideapad-acpi" by `cd` command and running `ls` there)

3. Use following command to turn on/off the conservation mode : (1 - conservation ON, 0 -conservation OFF)

> ```
> echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
> ```

> ```
> echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution.  Please take the [tour] to begin familiarizing your self with this community.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file: **/etc/default/tlp.conf**

- Uncomment the lines that has **START**/**STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0**/**1**
- For **non-ThinkPad** Lenovo set the **START** to dummy value of **0** and the **STOP** to **1**
- For any **ThinkPad** Lenovo set the **START/STOP** to any numbers of percentages you want
- For more info & examples visit:

  - https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/battery.html
  - https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/bc-vendors.html
- The 3 following steps are **optional**:

  1. Uncomment the line that has **TLP_ENABLE** and set it to **1**
  2. Uncomment the line that has **TLP_WARN_LEVEL** and set it to **3**
  3. Uncomment the line that has **NATACPI_ENABLE** driver and set it to **1** (*if **ThinkPad** enable the other 2 drivers as well*)

To apply new charging configurations for **current session only**:

`sudo tlp setcharge`

To apply new configurations **permanently** and start *tlp* in (auto mode):

`sudo tlp start`

(OPTIONAL) This command will be suggested by `tlp start` if needed:

`sudo systemctl enable tlp.service`

Answer (score 0):

sorry for being late.

I was having the same problem as you but I figured it out here: https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/bc-vendors.html.

I was using this thread as a guide, I am using arch linux on a ideapad and I managed to fix the problem. The TLP documentation site I linked is very extensive, most problems occur with lenovo and, mainly, thinkpad laptops. But don't worry, you are using an ideapad which uses a different battery firmware.

So, ideapads' batteries cannot have a custom battery threshold; they only accept the **Stop threshold values** which the firmware calls "battery conservation mode". It's boolean so it must be a 1 to enable or a 0 to disable. The **Start threshold values** should be a dummy value of 0.

The "battery conservation mode" functions like a set-in-stone battery threshold. *For me*, it turned on automatically once I set the STOP threshold to 1. But you may also try

> echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/bus/platform/drivers/ideapad_acpi/VPC2004:00/conservation_mode

... Such as another user posted. If it does not work, you may need to install the ideapad ACPI package and try again.

TL;DR: Change your STOP to 1 and your start to 0, let the battery discharge to 59% and run `sudo tlp-stat -b` to check if the battery conservation mode is active.

NOTE: Excuse my english, it's not my first language. Hope it helps.